# filter as you type in yii2 gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I need to filter the gridview as you type. By default it filters only when the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should handle this using your own js, e.g. :

```
$this->registerJs('$("body").on("keyup.yiiGridView", "#grid-id .filters input", function(){
    $("#grid-id").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
})', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

You should of course replace `grid-id` with appropriate id.

Comment: @SO-user: Its not working with Ajax i.e. `\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();`

Comment: yes, with ajax the grid reload and we lost the focus on the input as you type

Comment: @soju, how can i set the timeout ?