# Change GridView filters event type from onChange to onKeyPress in Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

Is it possible to change the event type associated to the input filters in GridViews from onChange to onKeyPress or something else?

Comment: you want to apply filter on key press right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter as you type in yii2 gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363461/filter-as-you-type-in-yii2-gridview)